# jquery - enable specific items in asp.net radiobuttonlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I know this has been asked before, but it is not working for my scenario.
**I have a jquery ui modal form** which contains a radiobuttonlist with static values:

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSlots" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
    <asp:ListItem Value="30" enabled="false">30 Minutes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="60" enabled="false">1 Hour</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="90" enabled="false">1 1/2 Hours</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="120" enabled="false">2 Hours</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="150" enabled="false">2 1/2 Hours</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="180" enabled="false">3 Hours</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Which of course renders as:

```
    <table id="rblSlots">
    <tr>
    <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="rblSlots_0" type="radio" name="rblSlots" value="30" disabled="disabled" /><label for="rblSlots_0">30 Minutes</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="rblSlots_1" type="radio" name="rblSlots" value="60" disabled="disabled" /><label for="rblSlots_1">1 Hour</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="rblSlots_2" type="radio" name="rblSlots" value="90" disabled="disabled" /><label for="rblSlots_2">1 1/2 Hours</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="rblSlots_3" type="radio" name="rblSlots" value="120" disabled="disabled" /><label for="rblSlots_3">2 Hours</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td><span disabled="disabled"><input id="rblSlots_4" type="radio" name="rblSlots" value="150" disabled="disabled" /><label for="rblSlots_4">2 1/2 Hours</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
    ...etc...
```

in my form opener dialog i make an ajax post to grab some vaues from my webservice among them 'timespan' in the following javascipt, i have set timespan to a static variable for debugging, i want to enable the radio buttons which are <= timespan.

```
    var strTS = "30,60,90,120,150,180";
    var aryTS = strTS.split(",");
    var timespan = 120;

    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {

        if ($('#rblSlots [value=' + aryTS[i] + ']').val() <= timespan) {

           $('#rblSlots [value=' + aryTS[i] + ']').removeAttr("disabled");

        }
    }

    $("#appointment-form").dialog("open");
    return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `prop` method:

```
$('#rblSlots input[value=' + timespan + ']').prop('disabled', false)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8q5Q3/)

Comment: That doesn't work eithe. I had tried .prop('disabled', false) 
too, I have other text box elements in other modal forms in my page which enable just fine using removeAttr. I am using jQuery 1.6.2. The 'input' tag you added doesnt make a difference, either way, if i add an alert in my for..loop above, i will get four alerts, 30, 60, 90, 120

Answer (score 0):

After clearing caches in IE and Firefox, it came to be that the above code does indeed work in Firefox, but for some reason it would not in IE. So I abandoned the method, for one that gave me a more esthetic look anyway.

Abandoned the RadioButtonList for Radio Buttons in a table.
Gave unique class names and style='display:none;' to the rows containing the Radio's.
and my javascript to:

```
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (aryTS[i] <= timespan) {
        $(".Slot_" + aryTS[i]).show();
      }
    }
```

Works fine in IE and Firefox